UNAVAILABLE: 502:Bad Gateway on Flink with PubSub source
I have a Flink 1.17.2 application running with Java 8. It's pulling messages from Google PubSub using PubSubSource connector. The app runs fine for around around 1 and a half day and then restarts with this messages:
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: 502:Bad Gateway
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.gcp.pubsub.shaded.com.google.pubsub.v1.SubscriberGrpc$SubscriberBlockingStub.acknowledge(SubscriberGrpc.java:1628)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.acknowledge(BlockingGrpcPubSubSubscriber.java:99)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.common.AcknowledgeOnCheckpoint.notifyCheckpointComplete(AcknowledgeOnCheckpoint.java:84)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.gcp.pubsub.PubSubSource.notifyCheckpointComplete(PubSubSource.java:208)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.notifyCheckpointComplete(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:127)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamOperatorWrapper.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamOperatorWrapper.java:104)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.notifyCheckpointComplete(RegularOperatorChain.java:145)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.notifyCheckpoint(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.notifyCheckpointComplete(SubtaskCheckpointCoordinatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.notifyCheckpointComplete(StreamTask.java:1430)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointCompleteAsync$16(StreamTask.java:1371)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.lambda$notifyCheckpointOperation$19(StreamTask.java:1410)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.runThrowing(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.Mail.run(Mail.java:90)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMail(MailboxProcessor.java:398)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMailsWhenDefaultActionUnavailable(MailboxProcessor.java:367)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.processMail(MailboxProcessor.java:352)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.mailbox.MailboxProcessor.runMailboxLoop(MailboxProcessor.java:229)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.runMailboxLoop(StreamTask.java:839)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:788)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:952)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:931)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:745)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:562)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I've found one thread on Google Cloud's repository stating that this was a bug and it's already fixed. Actually it says it was fixed many versions before 1.112.5 that is the one I'm using.
Does anybody have a clue?
